# Unity My viewport in my minimap is offset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My Viewport is offset for some reason, it used to work fine before i updated unity

This is my code

```
public RectTransform ViewPort;
public Transform Corner1, Corner2;



private Vector2 terrainSize;

private RectTransform mapRect;




// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    terrainSize = new Vector2(
        Corner2.position.x - Corner1.position.x,
        Corner2.position.z - Corner1.position.z);

    mapRect = GetComponent<RectTransform>();

}

public Vector2 WorldPositionToMap(Vector3 point)
{
    var pos = point - Corner1.position;
    var mapPos = new Vector2(
        point.x / terrainSize.x * mapRect.rect.width,
        point.z / terrainSize.y * mapRect.rect.height);
    return mapPos;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    ViewPort.position = WorldPositionToMap(Camera.main.transform.position);

}
```

[Here is a pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8To9E.jpg)

Everything with red has something to do with the minimap,

Comment: Please explain what's the problem elaborately. I don't think anyone would understand reading this description.

Comment: The problem is, that little viewport port in the bottom left, should be above the map.. but instead it keep going to the bottom left.

Comment: The thing is the parent is the map and the viewport is the child, but instead staying inside the parent it goes to the bottom leave of the whole canavas

Comment: Look at the picture at the bottom