# GameObject.Instantiate(Prefab) Isn't working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The problem is that I can't Object. Instantiate, It keep giving me a error I tells me "An embedded statement may not be a declaration or labeled statement".

Im have tried these options to

```
var go = (GameObject)Instantiate(BuildingPrefab);
var go = Instantiate(BuildingPrefab) as GameObject;
GameObject go = Instantiate(prefab);
```

And im kind of new to unity so any suggestions, what im doing wrong

```
public class FindBuildingSite : MonoBehaviour
{

public float MaxBuildDistance = 30;
public GameObject BuildingPrefab;
public PlayerSetupDefinition Info;
public Transform source;

Renderer rend;
Color Red = new Color(1, 0, 0, 0.5f);
Color Green = new Color(0, 1, 0, 0.5f);

private void Start()
{
    MouseManager.Current.enabled = false;
    rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    var tempTarget = RtsManager.Current.ScreenPointToMapPosition(Input.mousePosition);
    if (tempTarget.HasValue == false)
        return;

    transform.position = tempTarget.Value;

    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, source.position) > MaxBuildDistance)
    {
        rend.material.color = Red;
        return;
    }


    if (RtsManager.Current.IsGameObejctSafeToPlace(gameObject))
    {
        rend.material.color = Green;
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        var go = UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate(BuildingPrefab);
        go.transform.position = transform.position;
        go.AddComponent<Player>().Info = Info;
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
    else
    {
        rend.material.color = Red;
    }


}

private object Instantiate(object prefab)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private void OnDestroy()
{
    MouseManager.Current.enabled = true;
}
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems such as this can often be [caused by its surrounding code](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/696530/an-embedded-statement-may-not-be-a-declaration-or.html).

Your line `if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))` needs brackets around all of it's contained code.

When it's compiled, it effectively reads like this..

```
   if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
   {
      var go = UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate(BuildingPrefab);
   }

    go.transform.position = transform.position;
    go.AddComponent<Player>().Info = Info;
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
```

Without brackets on the if statement, it will only read the line immediately after it.

Your next line is trying to use a reference to `go`, which at that point may or may not exist.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!, Do u think u can help me with something else to?

Comment: If the answer has helped you, please consider 'Accepting' my answer and +1 :)

I'd be happy to help further, but if it's a longer question, it may be better off as a new question.

Comment: Can i write to you in private?

Comment: Sorry, we can't private message.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46259901/unity-my-viewport-in-my-minimap-is-offset

Comment: Look at this problem, i just posted

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with that one, sorry.